# Delete IDs that repeat more then once, but leave the first occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table and need to delete entire row where ID occurs second and subsequent times, but leave the first occurrence of suCustomerIDBy the way. M table has ID which is a primary key and CustometID which is duplicated. So I need to remove all rows with duplicated CustomerID.

```
Delete From Table1 where ID IN (select ID From Table1 where count(distinct CutomerID) >=2 group by CustomerID)
```

The code above will delete all id including the first occurrence of each of the IDs, but I need to keep their first occurrence. Please advise.

Comment: Do you have another column that is unique?

Comment: How do you know which occurance is first?

Comment: Yes, there is a row_id which is a primery key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should give you what you need.

There may be better ways to do it if you can provide the full table schema for Table1

If you obtain the row number and then just ignore the first ones:

```
;WITH cte 
AS 
(
  SELECT ID, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS Rn
  FROM [Table1]
)
DELETE cte WHERE Rn > 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to adjyst it to my particular need and will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
delete a from(
Select dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS Rn,*
from Table1)a
where a.Rn>1
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.